# why am i getting an "error: not a statement" message?

Tags: java

The idea for the program is to establish a users name, ask for 3 variables that i assigned as doubles, and use these variables to calculate various equasions. My first error is on the line that states; 
 **System.out.print ("The area of a trapazoid is ") + (h * (a + b)/2);**
I am getting an 'error: not a statement' with an arrow pointing to the first plus sign. ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineberryCorey
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userName;
    double a;
    double b;
    double h;

    System.out.print ("What is your first name?");
        userName = stdIn.nextString();

    System.out.print ("Alright, " + userName + ". Give me a number.");

        a = stdIn.nextDouble();

    System.out.print ("give me another number.");

        b = stdIn.nextDouble();

    System.out.print ("Give me one more number.");

        h = stdIn.nextDouble();

    System.out.print ("using the date you provided...");
    System.out.print ("The area of a trapazoid is ") + (h * (a + b)/2);
    System.out.print ("The surface area of a box is ") + (2 * ((a * b) + (a * h) + (b * h)));
    System.out.print ("The surface area of a sphere with radius ") + a + (" is ") + (4 * MATH.PI * (a * a));
    System.out.print ("The volume of a sphere with radius ") + b + (" is ") + (4 * MATH.PI * (b * b * b) / 3);
    System.out.print ("The volume of a spherical cap is ") + (MATH.PI * (h * h) * (3 * a - h) / 3);
    System.out.print ("The volume of a frustum is ") + (MATH.PI * h * ((a * a) + (a * b) + (b * b)) / 3);
    System.out.print ("The volume of a torus with radii of ") + a + (" and ") + b + (" is "((MATH.PI * MATH.PI) *
(((a + b) * (b - a)) * ((a + b) * (b - a))) / 4);

    } 
}
```

Comment: It should be `System.out.print ("The area of a trapazoid is " + (h * (a + b)/2));`

Comment: Either you miscounted your parentheses, or you misunderstood Java syntax. `System.out.print` is a function that takes one argument and has return type `void`, so you cannot use it as operand to any operator.

Comment: It is likely both. I am very new using java, and have a low level of understanding of how to troubleshoot the errors I am getting. I appreciate your contribution, as it took me closer to the end goal, but i am afraid it still wont compile.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct all System.out.print() syntax:**

```
//correct the code:
System.out.print ("The area of a trapazoid is"  + (h * (a + b)/2));
System.out.print ("The surface area of a box is " + (2 * ((a * b) + (a * h) + (b * h))));
System.out.print ("The surface area of a sphere with radius " + a + " is " + (4 * MATH.PI * (a * a)));
System.out.print ("The volume of a sphere with radius " + b + " is " + (4 * MATH.PI * (b * b * b) / 3));
System.out.print ("The volume of a spherical cap is " + (MATH.PI * (h * h) * (3 * a - h) / 3));
System.out.print ("The volume of a frustum is " + (MATH.PI * h * ((a * a) + (a * b) + (b * b)) / 3));
```

Why you are concatenating `sysout` statements,

```
(" is ")// here parenthesis not required.
```

Comment: I am attempting to compile these math equasions in conjunction to the text string. I am in the early stages of learning how to write code, and corrected my paranthesis issue. Now my error reads "cannot find symbol" with regard to "userName = stdIn.nextString()"

Comment: for String use stdIn.next() or stdIn.nextLine().. try this @Corey